# how to create a loop that creates lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a loop that makes lists the name of the lists that need to come from another list.

I tried doing it like that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
   {
       List<string> Name[i] = new List<string>();
   }
```

Comment: You cannot build variable names

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the source collection in the list constructor, like this

```
var newList = new List<string>(Names);
```

If you want more control, you can still do your loop, but declare the destination list first:

```
var newList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
{
    newList.Add(Names[i]);
}
```

And finally, if you need a list of lists, where each list is named, you'd use a different data structure, for example a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead:

```
var listOfLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
{
    listOfLists.Add(
        Names[i], // <--- the name of the list is the key
        new()     // <--- the named list (initially empty)
    );
}
```

Which, in modern C#, can be shortened further to become

```
var listOfLists = Names.ToDictionary(name => name, _ => new List<string>());
```

Comment: `var listOfLists = Names.ToDictionary(name => name, name => new List<string>());`